# Concrete Mathematics: Josephus Problem: Odd induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I am trying to work through the odd induction case of the closed form solution to the Josephus problem. To start with a quick review of the even case - I'm being quite verbose though to help frame the question and also to potentially highlight any mistakes in my understanding that just happen to work in the even case.

#### Quick review of even case

Recurrence: $J(2n) = 2J(n) - 1$

Closed form to prove: $J(2^m+l)=2l+1$

First we express it in terms of the recurrence

$$J(2^m+l)=2J(2^{m-1}+\frac{l}{2})-1$$

Logically, then, these two are equivalent

$$2J(2^{m-1}+\frac{l}{2})-1=2(\frac{2l}{2}+1)-1$$

Which finally gives us what we want

$$2(\frac{2l}{2}+1)-1=2(l+1)-1=2l+2-1=2l+1$$

#### Odd case

Odd recurrence: $J(2n+1)=2J(n)+1$

I am trying to apply the closed form in the same way. First in terms of the odd recurrence:

$$J(2^m+l)=2J(2^{m-1}+\frac{l}{2})+1$$

Then plugging in the closed form:

$$2(2\frac{l}{2}+1)+1$$

But then this does not induct:

$$2(\frac{l}{2}+1)+1=2(l+1)+1=2l+3$$

I am not sure what I am misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re not applying the recurrence for the odd case correctly. Suppose that $2n+1=2^m+\ell$, where $0\le\ell<2^m$. The recurrence is $J(2n+1)=2J(n)+1$, and $n$ here is $\frac12(2^m+\ell-1)$, so

$$\begin{align*}
J(2^m+\ell)&=2J\left(2^{m-1}+\frac{\ell-1}2\right)+1\\
&=2\left(\frac{2(\ell-1)}2+1\right)+1\\
&=2\ell+1\;,
\end{align*}$$

as desired.